# How can I solve the body property to display color in CSS for Codepen?

Tags: html, css, codepen

I'm trying to add color in the body property of my CSS in Codepen. Have not added anything but the title to the webpage, but it does not changes color regardless of where I put the tag. Tried to place the `<body>` html tag before `<head>`, erased `<main>`, still no change.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Project Survey Form</title>
    </head>
    <body id="body">    
        <main>
            <h1 id="title">Survey Form</h1>

        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<style>

body {
    background-color: blue;
}

</style>
```

It keeps displaying the white background. Do you know of any workaround for this?

Comment: Is the code here *exactly* as you have it in the HTML and CSS panes in CodePen?

Comment: Don't put **HTML** (i.e. `<style>` tags) in the box marked CSS.

Comment: @TylerH I just erased the <body id="body> and left it just as <body>. After that, it's exactly like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codepen at **CSS section**, you don't need style tag

```
<style>

body {
    background-color: blue;
}

</style>
```

to

```
   body {
        background-color: blue;
    }
```